# Factory reset Apple bluetooth device in Monterey

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, monterey

Under older versions of macOS, holding Shift+Option while clicking the Bluetooth dropdown menu would yield additional options, including a "Debug" > "Factory reset all connected Apple devices" option, and a per-device "Factory Reset" option for Apple devices.

In Monterey, these options are both missing. These are at times necessary, for example to fix lag from an Apple keyboard (which is not solved by resetting the bluetooth module).

How can we perform these operations in Monterey?

Answer (score 1):

Restart and hold down Shift to enter Safe Boot mode, to flush caches.

Then delete this file: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`

Reboot normally then re-pair your device(s).

You may also wish to file [Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) with Apple requesting that this functionality (present in Big Sur and earlier) is restored in a future macOS release.

Comment: this file does not exist for me

Comment: deleting this file doesn't remove the paired device history. They're stored in /Library/Bluetooth/Preferences/com.apple.MobileBluetooth.devices.plist